# Can not access windows share via host name but can via ip address from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Recently, I changed my router and now I cannot access share folders in my windows machine via hostname from my ubuntu. Other windows machines can still access them. My windows PC has avast firewall. Have solution?

Edit: I solved the problem.

Comment: What did you change on the router?

Comment: Nothing change. Just put the new router in.